# How do i pass a variable to multiple layers of components? Ex. Passing to a productCard page, then to a products page to display all cards

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner. I've been making small iterations to make my webpage more dynamic with less components. I have mapped variable that's looping through local hardcoded state in the app.js page. It's main goal is to create multiple cards for each product. After creating this card, I want to get access to this variable and display it on a page called "products." How would i pass this 'equipment' variable to a "products" page. I want to display all cards on that page.

```
  const equipment = (
    <div>
      {this.state.equipment.map( (item, index) => {
        return <ProductCard
          name={item.name}
          description={item.description}
          price={item.price}
          review={item.review}
          image={item.image}
          key={item.id}/>
        })}
      </div>
    )
```

In other words, is there a way to get access to this variable that's located on the app.js page, and display it on the Products.js page. The cards are already displaying fine on the app.js page when testing.

Previously, i would just render state in stateless components using hooks, but that would mean i'd have to create json files or hard code the object on each page. For example, if i had a 'socks' page, the array of objects would be on this page, if i had a tshirts page, all objects would be on the tshirts.js page etc, then i would create a map function to loop through.

Edit**

```
    <Router>
      <Navbar/>
      <SubNavbar/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
        <Route exact path="/products" component={Products}/>
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
        <Route exact path="/equipment" render={ (props) => <Equipment equipment2={equipment}/>}/>
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Comment: Can you add some more information about how/if you're doing routing? Are your "pages" actually different URLs or just rendering a different state?

Comment: Have you tried passing `equipment` as a prop to the component in the products page? It's a little unclear what you're trying to accomplish without any shared component code. What component owns `equipment` and what component are you trying to render it? How do they relate to one another?

Comment: Sorry, yeah so i'm using react router to render each page of product listings. I'm doing basically a fitness equipment products website. For example, there will be a various products for barbells, plates, equipment, etc. Each of these objects are hardcoded into the app.js instead of reaching out to a json server. I already created a productcard for each item of barbells, plates, equipment, etc. But i want to dynamically display these cards on each page

Comment: I would guess that your data/state lives inside of app.js, as does your route definitions? On each route you define a component, so you can pass props to this page component there. So in your main page, once a user selects a product, store that in your state in app.js and pass that state to the next component for the product details route. If you share your router code we might give more exact examples

Comment: Alright i posted the router code. Is that what you're saying to do? For the <Route exact path="equipment" line?

Comment: How do you determine what equipment to display? There are many ways to pass "data", including several in just `react-router-dom` alone, like match params (i.e. "/equipment/:equipmentCatagory"), or route state (i.e. the link to "/equipment" sends the equipment array in route state). Is that also determined in `App.js`?

Comment: Sorry I ended up getting this resolved. In the page that i wanted to display the cards (ProductListings.js), I wasn't calling the right variable. It wasn't accessing what was passed in from the render method of the Route.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user selects their product category on the Products page, you can do this:

```
<Router>
    <Navbar />
    <SubNavbar />
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route exact path="/products" render={(props) => <Products onSelect={(category) => /* setState({ category })} />} />
        <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route exact path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route exact path="/categories" render={(props) => <ProductList items={/* state.category.items */} />} />
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RESOLVED::

//create product cards or free weights
    const freeWeights = (
      <div className="all-cards">
        {this.state.freeWeights.map( (item, index) => {
          return <ProductCard
            name={item.name}
            description={item.description}
            price={item.price}
            review={item.review}
            image={item.image}
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}/>
          })}
        </div>
      )

      //create productcards for equipment
      const equipment = (
        <div className="all-cards">
          {this.state.equipment.map( (item, index) => {
            return <ProductCard
              name={item.name}
              description={item.description}
              price={item.price}
              review={item.review}
              image={item.image}
              key={item.id}
              id={item.id}/>
            })}
          </div>
        )

        //create productcards for barbells
        const barbells = (
          <div className="all-cards">
              {this.state.barbells.map( (item, index) => {
                return <ProductCard
                  name={item.name}
                  description={item.description}
                  price={item.price}
                  review={item.review}
                  image={item.image}
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}/>
                })}
            </div>
          )

        //create productcards for barbells
        const plates = (
          <div className="all-cards">
              {this.state.plates.map( (item, index) => {
                return <ProductCard
                  name={item.name}
                  description={item.description}
                  price={item.price}
                  review={item.review}
                  image={item.image}
                  key={item.id}
                  id={item.id}/>
                })}
            </div>
          )

          const shoes = (
            <div className="all-cards">
                {this.state.shoes.map( (item, index) => {
                  return <ProductCard
                    name={item.name}
                    description={item.description}
                    price={item.price}
                    review={item.review}
                    image={item.image}
                    key={item.id}
                    id={item.id}/>
                  })}
              </div>
            )


The <Router> on app.js: 

 <Router>
          <Navbar/>
          <SubNavbar/>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route exact path="/equipment" render={ (props) => <ProductListings {...props} equipmentCards={equipment} />}/>
            <Route exact path="/barbells" render={ (props) => <ProductListings {...props} barbellCards={barbells} />}/>
            <Route exact path="/plates" render={ (props) => <ProductListings {...props} plateCards={plates} />}/>
            <Route exact path="/shoes" render={ (props) => <ProductListings {...props} shoeCards={shoes} />}/>
            <Route exact path="/products" render={ (props) => <ProductListings {...props} plateCards={plates} equipmentCards={equipment} barbellCards={barbells} />}/>

          </Switch>
      </Router>  


Then on the ProductListings.js page (page to display all cards):

export default function ProductListings(passedCards, props) {

    return(
        <div className="main-container">
        <Spring
            from={{ opacity: 0, marginRight: -800}}
            to={{ opacity: 1, marginRight: 0}}

        >
            { props => (
                <div className="products-wrapper" style={props} >
                    <div className="sidebar">
                        <Filter/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="products-listings">
                        {passedCards.equipmentCards}
                        {passedCards.barbellCards}
                        {passedCards.plateCards}
                        {passedCards.shoeCards}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </Spring>
    </div>
```